# Is there an editing tool to create a binary PE file in windows?

Tags: reverse-engineering, portable-executable

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716137/is-there-a-command-line-tool-to-get-the-machine-code-for-an-assembly-instruction/3720358#3720358) provided a way to create a binary file in linux, is there such a convenient tool for windows?

Comment: The linker does this.  What are you trying to create the binary from?

Comment: No,I need an editing tool to do this.Just to facilitate learning PE.

Answer (score 1):

Try LordPE or PEBrowser.

Comment: It is an error start from scratch a PE. Leave it to the linker. Compile a simple program, open it with a PE Editor and modify all that you want. Check this http://www.woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/index.php/Category:RCE_Tools

Answer (score 1):

You can start from here: http://www.phreedom.org/solar/code/tinype/ , then modify one of the files using a PE editor (e.g. CFF Explorer).

Programmatically, in Python you can use pefile to read/write the PE structure.

Answer (score 0):

Recompile those tools on windows? Shouldn't be too hard to do against a cygwin or mingw base environment.